# Using PartialView as resusable html code with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC 5 and I have a partial view which renders a styled select:

```
  @model Int16
  <div class="select">
    <span class="arr"></span>
    <select>
        <option>2016</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Notice the model. I'm passing in an int that will change the width of the select. This is how I render the partial view in Index.cshtml and other views:

```
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Components/_select.cshtml",(short) 300)
```

So in this example, I want the select to have a width of 300px. I added the following javascript in my partial view, so now it looks like this:

```
@model Int16
<script>
    $(function () {
        debugger;
        var width = '@Model';
        if (width !== '') {
            $('div.select select').css(width, width + 'px');
        }
    });
  </script>
 }
<div class="select">
  <span class="arr"></span>
  <select>
    <option>2016</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Two problems:

1. The code isn't working. The javascript isn't being called, so the width of the select is not changing. The debugger statement is not being hit.
2. I don't like the javascript being inside the partial view. I will have a page with 8 of these selects (hence the reason for the reusable html) but with the javascript being in the partial view, that code will be on the page 8 times. Very inefficient.

First and foremost, how do I get the javascript to fire in a partial view? (I would like this answered because I cant see for the life of me why it isn't firing).

Next,what would be a better place to put the javascript so the width of the selects inside the partial view will be changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace your JavaScript code with CSS. In fact, you just add css property to html element using your code. So, why just not to write a CSS rule?

```
@model Int16

<style>
    div.select select { width: @(Model.ToString() + "px") }
</style>
<div class="select">
  <span class="arr"></span>
  <select>
    <option>2016</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case I don't think you even need javascript - Make use of Razer directly on the select element instead.

```
@model Int16
<div class="select">
  <span class="arr"></span>
  <select style="width: @string.Format("{0}px", Model)">
    <option>2016</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked...I used string interpolation: <select style="width: @($"{Model}px")"></select>

Answer (score 0):

Well for one your script end tag is inside your function.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        debugger;
        var width = '@Model';
        if (width !== '') {
            $('div.select select').css(width, width + 'px');
        }
    });
 }
</script>
```

As for having javascript directly in your view, you can get the code in a seperate file and put only a reference src in your partial view. Such as this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/exemple.js")"></script>
```

Comment: Honestly, I have a scripts section in my _layout and when i copied the code, I omitted this. So the script tag is in the correct place.